# Eclipse: Howto bind an activity to a view

Tags: eclipse, android-activity, rcp

For my Eclipse rcp application I want to use activities to show and hide some views. I read the Eclipse documentation about activities and tried to get a working example based on the *'Using expression-based activities'* snippets from the documentation.

In the first step i created a new view and add a placeholder for it in my perspective class:

```
layout.addPlaceholder(View1.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.5f, layout.getEditorArea());
```

Then i added my activity with a *'enabled when'* expression and a binding:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity id="org.project.activities.activity1" name="myActivity">
       <enabledWhen>
           <with variable="org.project.activities.sessionState">
               <equals value="loggedIn"></equals>
           </with>
       </enabledWhen>
    </activity>
</extension>
<activityPatternBinding
    activityId="org.project.activities.activity1"
    pattern="org.project.activities/org.project.activities.View1">
</activityPatternBinding>
```

In the last step i added my source-provider:

```
public class ActivitiySourceProvider extends AbstractSourceProvider {
   public static final String SESSION_STATE = "org.project.activities.sessionState";
   private static final String LOGGED_OUT = "loggedOut";
   private static final String LOGGED_IN = "loggedIn";
   private static final String[] SOURCE_NAMES = new String[] { SESSION_STATE };
   private boolean loggedIn = false;

   @Override
   public Map<String, String> getCurrentState() {
       Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
       String value = loggedIn ? LOGGED_IN : LOGGED_OUT;
       map.put(SESSION_STATE, value);
       return map;
   }

   @Override
   public String[] getProvidedSourceNames() {
       return SOURCE_NAMES;
   }

   public void setLoggedIn() {
       loggedIn = !loggedIn;
       String value = loggedIn ? LOGGED_IN : LOGGED_OUT;
       fireSourceChanged(ISources.WORKBENCH, SESSION_STATE, value);
   }
}
```

When I start the test application my view *'`View1`'* is hidden and when I toggle my variable the view is still hidden. To toggle my variable i used a handle and i don't receive any exceptions. I also tried to set my variable to explicit to *'loggedOut'* at the application start, but i didn't worked either.

Did I missed something from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your `ActivitySourceProvider` as source provider in an extension for extension point `org.eclipse.ui.services`? Otherwise it won't be used for expression evaluation.

Comment: Yes I did and i tested the source-provider with an _'enabledWhen'_ expression for a handler and it worked fine.

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind is that your `activityPatternBinding` has no parameter `isEqualityPattern`. If not set, it defaults to false, meaning that the pattern is compiled into a regular expression. You probably want to have a direct comparison, i.e. `isEqualityPattern` should be `true`.

Comment: Hello, i tried it with `isEqualityPattern = true` but i did not work either.